# Why does Path.Combine ignore the first part of a ftp server path?

Tags: c#, .net, filepath

I have two parts of a ftp server path. Let's name the /one and /two.

The full path I want to achieve is /one/two.

When I use `System.IO.Path.Combine("/one", "/two");` the output is `"/two"`.

Why is that so? I expected it to be "/one/two" as you would normally with windows paths.

Is this by design, wrong usage by me or a bug in the .net class (unlikely)?

(How) can I use System.IO.Path functionality to produce "/one/two"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If `path2` contains an absolute path, this method returns `path2`.